# Does $\sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^k$ converge for even $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

This question was motivated by an misleading question of my own. If there already exists the same question (which I did not find), please mark this question as duplicate.

Take a look at the limit of this series:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{2n}_{k=1} (-1)^k.
$$
**Question:** Does this limit exist? Does the series converge or diverge?

$ $

> **Argumentation A**
>
> We can rewrite the sum as
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{2n}_{k=1} (-1)^k = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} (-1 +1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} 0 = 0.$$
>   Hence it converges.

$ $

> **Argumentation B**
>
> We can rewrite the sum as
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{2n}_{k=1} (-1)^k = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} (-1) = -1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ....$$
>   Hence it diverges.

$ $

**Which argumentation is correct?**

Comment: In order for a series to converge, its sequence must converge to zero (and that is a necessary condition!), meaning the infinite term must go to zero. That's not happening in your case. Your series cannot be convergent

Comment: @imranfat: no, the general term is $-1+1=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So the series stated in the title converges too? As long as $n$ is finite, ok. But when $n$ is infinite, I find that hard to digest

Comment: @imranfat: the title specifies $n$ even. Do you deny that $\sum0$ converges ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not contest/deny anything. I find it a little hard to work with "eveness" and "oddness" when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @imranfat: forget about parity. The general term is $T_n=-1+1$.

Comment: @imranfat That's exactly the reason why I was posting the question :) it's confusing...

Comment: @FabianSchn.: no confusion at all. Every term in the series is $0$, and so are all partial sums.

Comment: It is, in a way, though A would be the better choice. As long as $n$ is finite, no matter how big, then for sure it is convergent. It is the infinite part that is troubling me, though I understand that you are adding " in pairs" hence adding zero. I think for sake of application, zero would be acceptable. Maybe other's can weigh in

Comment: @imranfat: yes, you are adding in pairs, by the definition. $(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez: that's precisely where the false confusion stems from. The given series is *not* a Grandi's. The partial sums of Grandi are $1,0,1,0,1,\cdots$. The series of the OP goes $0,0,0,0,0\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument A is correct.

In argument B the first equal sign is false. In general the notation 
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is shorthand for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.  So what you are claiming is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}a_k$ which need not hold if both sides don't converge.

Answer (score 1):

As $\forall n:S_{n}=0$, the sequence converges to $0$ (fairly quickly ).

The argumentation "B" doesn't account for the fact that you only consider the even numbers of terms.